# Unable to scrape the contents from registry.terraform with request module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the contents on the left side under `azurerm_provider` from [this webpage](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management) using the requests module.

I've explored dev tools to find any links containing the expected results, but I failed to locate anything. I've also looked for the content in the page source in case it is within some script tags, but I also failed to find anything.

I've already found success grabbing the content using selenium, so I do not wish to go that route.

This is my failed attempt using the requests module:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers.update(headers)
    res = session.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("ul.provider-docs-menu-list .menu-list-category"):
        category_name = item.select_one("a.menu-list-category-link span.menu-list-category-link-title").get_text(strip=True)
        category_content = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in item.select("li.menu-list-link > a")]
        print(category_name,category_content)
```

Expected output:

```
Azure Provider: Authenticating via a Service Principal and a Client Certificate
Azure Provider: Authenticating via a Service Principal and a Client Secret
Azure Provider: Authenticating via a Service Principal and OpenID Connect
Azure Provider: Authenticating via Managed Identity
Azure Provider: Authenticating via the Azure CLI
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashicorp builds their documentation dynamically from API calls.

You need to get the provider version and then fetch the provider docs.
Finally, you can request docs body using the provider docs link.

For example:

```py
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate

provider_versions = "https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-versions/38614?include=provider-docs"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers.update(headers)
    provider_docs = session.get(provider_versions).json()
    docs = [
        [
            doc['attributes']['title'],
            f"https://registry.terraform.io{doc['links']['self']}",
        ]
        for doc in provider_docs['included']
    ]
    print(tabulate(docs, headers=['Title', 'Link']))
```

This should output:

```bash
Title                                                                            Link
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ------------------------------------------------------
private_dns_resolver_dns_forwarding_ruleset                                      https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2530275
sentinel_threat_intelligence_indicator                                           https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2530362
proximity_placement_group                                                        https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2529517
bot_channel_sms                                                                  https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2529741
elastic_cloud_elasticsearch                                                      https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2529924
key_vault_certificate_contacts                                                   https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2530018
netapp_volume                                                                    https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2530213
site_recovery_hyperv_replication_policy                                          https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2530388
subscription_policy_assignment                                                   https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2530499
automation_webhook                                                               https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2529715
dev_test_linux_virtual_machine                                                   https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2529897
express_route_connection                                                         https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2529945
kusto_iothub_data_connection                                                     https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2530039
logz_sub_account_tag_rule                                                        https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2530094
private_dns_txt_record                                                           https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2529511
log_analytics_cluster                                                            https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2530063
machine_learning_workspace                                                       https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2529442
dev_test_virtual_network                                                         https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2529900
private_endpoint                                                                 https://registry.terraform.io/v2/provider-docs/2530284

and much more ...
```

Then, using the links you can get the documentation's content.

For example:

```py
    # Get the first doc and its body
    first_doc = session.get(docs[0][1]).json()
    print(first_doc['data']['attributes']['content'])
```

This should give you:

```
---
subcategory: "IoT Hub"
layout: "azurerm"
page_title: "Azure Resource Manager: azurerm_iothub_device_update_instance"
description: |-
  Manages an IoT Hub Device Update Instance.
---

# azurerm_iothub_device_update_instance

Manages an IoT Hub Device Update Instance.

## Example Usage

>> truncated <<
```